# Powershell pathname variable

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm very new to Powershell scripting after doing some online courses and I have been set a task to clear down a template backup folder, and move the existing templates to the backup folder.

The script itself I've created with no issues (I hope), however, we want this script to work for both our PROD and DEVTEST environments - the filepath varies.

How do I create a variable for the filepath to the systemfiles folder?

I could have two separate variables but want to have it as one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
. "$PSScriptRoot\functions.ps1"

$consul_address =       $env:bamboo_consul_address
$our_environment =      $env:bamboo_our_environment
$location =             $env:bamboo_location

$systemfilespath =     
"\\oursite.com\shares\APPSystemFiles\${our_environment}" # DEVTEST env locations

"\\oursite\applications\APPLICATIONNAME\Systemfiles\${our_environment}" # PROD env locations

{
Write-Host "Clearing the content on Printing Template Backups from ${our_environment}"

Remove-Item "${systemfilespath}\PrintingRoot\PrintingTemplateBackup/*" 

(Move-Item -Path "${systemfilespath}\PrintingRoot\PrintingTemplate/*") 
| ForEach-Object
Write-Host "Backing up Printing Template Backup file with Printing Template 
file from ${our_environment}" 
| Set-Content -Path 
"${systemfilespath}\PrintingRoot\PrintingTemplateBackup/*" 
}
```

Comment: Hello,
You could create `$systemfilespath` as an array of paths.
and for each path perform any action you want.

`$systemfilespath = @( 
"\\oursite.com\shares\APPSystemFiles\${our_environment}",
 "\\oursite\applications\APPLICATIONNAME\Systemfiles\${our_environment}")

Foreach ($path in $systemfilespath) {%your code here%}
`

Comment: You're using `{ }` all over the place, none of them are _actually_ needed in your script. I'd recommend reading [about_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables) as in 99% cases they will just be `$var`

Comment: or if your environments are isolated from each other you could use this logic:

`if (Test-path "\\oursite.com\shares\APPSystemFiles\${our_environment}") {$systemfilespath =     
"\\oursite.com\shares\APPSystemFiles\${our_environment}"}
elseif (Test-Path "\\oursite\applications\APPLICATIONNAME\Systemfiles\${our_environment}") {$systemfilespath = \\oursite\applications\APPLICATIONNAME\Systemfiles\${our_environment}"}`
it will check path availability and based on result set `$systemfilespath = ` variable to either prod or test environment

sorry if it's not what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If there are a set number of options that you would need to choose from and the script is going to be triggered manually to start, you could prompt for the location you are wanting to affect.

```
$systemfilespath = Read-Host -Prompt "Choose a Location"
        Switch ($systemfilespath){
                1 {CLS ; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "\\oursite.com\shares\APPSystemFiles\${our_environment}"} # or a desc
                2 {CLS ; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "\\oursite\applications\APPLICATIONNAME\Systemfiles\${our_environment}"} # or a desc
                }
```